# Python find and replace dialog from Rapid GUI Programming error

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, importerror

When building the find and replace dialog from "Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt (Chapter 07), by Prentice Hall (Mark Sumerfield)", I get the following error:

```
    import ui_findandreplacedlg
ImportError: No module named ui_findandreplacedlg
```

Depending on which version of python I run, I also get:

```
File "findandreplacedlg.py", line 7, in <module>  
    ui_findandreplacedlg.Ui_FindAndReplaceDlg):  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Ui_FindAndReplaceDlg'
```

I got the source code from their website and it errors on the same line in the same way. I've searched the errata on their webpage with no mention whatsoever. Does anyone know what the solution is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `ui` files using the `pyuic` tool. This is explained in the book as follows (page 206):

> Once a user interface has been designed and saved in a .ui file, it
>   must be con- verted into code before it can be used. This is done
>   using the pyuic4 command- line program. For example:
>
> ```
> C:\pyqt\chap07>pyuic4 -o ui_findandreplacedlg.py findandreplacedlg.ui
> ```

Or if you're on Linux:

```
$ cd pyqt/chap07
$ pyuic4 -o ui_findandreplacedlg.py findandreplacedlg.ui
$ python findandreplacedlg.py
```

Comment: @Julia. I tested with [pyqtbook27.tar.gz](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook27.tar.gz) and [pyqtbook31.tar.gz](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook31.tar.gz), and they both work fine for me. You need to run the program with `python findandreplacedlg.py` (after you `cd` into the appropriate directory).

Comment: I thought I had used pyuic4 but when retracing my steps I noticed that when I thought I used pyuic4 and pyuic I only have pyuic and pyside-uic installed.

Comment: I now am having a problem installing pyuic4 from source. I will open a new thread for it.

Answer (score 0):

The code in question can be found here - https://github.com/suzp1984/pyqt5-book-code/blob/master/chap07/ui_findandreplacedlg.py. If that file is in the same directory as the code you're trying to run, just do

```
import ui_findandreplacedlg
```

Comment: Yes, I have the file included in the same folder. It is still the same error.